# Something is blocking the traffic in Ubuntu localhost on Azure

Tags: azure, docker, ubuntu, localhost, virtual-machine

I have a web app running on docker in an Ubuntu Server Virtual Machine on Azure.

I have opened all networking ports to localhost from the networking tab in the Azure Portal, but the site does not load correctly using the static IP from Azure. (images missing, page loading without controls).

There is no firewall enabled in the Server. Is there something else that could be blocking the traffic?

The site works fine inside the VM. When accessing it from outside is when it shows the issues.

Comment: if the site loads but something are missing its not azure blocking it, something wrong with your ubuntu or webserver or html etc

Comment: The site works fine inside the VM. When accessing it from outside is when it shows the issues.

Comment: like i said, nothing in default azure vm setup can partially block traffic, something is wrong with your http server or html code

Comment: Then it is either a Docker/Ubuntu issue. Do you have any expertise? Can you tell me a way to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: @GeorgiaKalyva Please add the command you used to run the container, and the error message  when it occurs.

Comment: please delete extra stuff @Light.G

Comment: @Light.G docker-compose up is the command. Runs with no errors and the app loads fine if I use firefox to open the site inside the VM. When I open the site using the <VM IP>:Port from my PC the site loads partially. I have changed the hosts file and added this line 
127.0.0.1     openloyalty.localhost
Does that pose an issue?

Comment: @GeorgiaKalyva Then docker-compose file maybe needed. If it pleases you, you could update question directly every time when other people ask for more information.

Comment: You can try to add the rule for listening to 0.0.0.0:port, the port is which you expose for container of your web app to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This is the error that shows up

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

The app sees a different IP and all api calls are blocked. I will try to find a solution there. Thank you everyone who responded!